# Solving $\psi_{xxx} + (u(x) - (ik)^3))\psi = 0$ for $x > 0$, $k \in \mathbb C$, and $u(x)$ smooth

Tags: differential-equations, integral-kernel

I was reading *Initial-Boundary Value Problems for Linear PDEs with Variable Coefficients* by P. Treharne and A. S. Fokas, when I came across the following ODE formulated as part of a Lax pair for a linear system $q_t + q_{xxx} + u(x)q = 0$.

The authors claim that for $x > 0$, $k \in \mathbb C$, and a smooth $u(x)$ that decays to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, the ODE.
$$\psi_{xxx} +  (u(x) - (ik)^3))\psi = 0$$
has a solution given in terms of the following inhomgenous Fredholm integral equation
$$\psi(x,k) = f(x,k) + \frac{1}{3k^2} \int_0^x \left(\sum_{j=0}^{2}\alpha^j e^{i\alpha^jk(x - \xi)}u(\xi)\right) \psi(\xi,k)d\xi$$
where
$$f(x,k) = e^{i\alpha^j k x}$$
for $0\leq j \leq 2$ and $\alpha = \exp(2\pi i /3)$.

I have two questions.

1. How does one derive this solution? It appears to be similar to solving a first order ODE by using an integrating factor.
2. Is the integral kernel separable in that it may be written as $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_j(\xi) \beta_j(k)$? I don't believe that the answer is affirmative due to the $k(x-\xi)$ term, but I am curious to know if there is a different means of separating it.

*Note:* Although this question is not research level, I originally posed it on Math Stack Exchange 4 days ago. No one answered it, so I decided to delete it and instead ask it here.